# using insight or ddd with working gdb session

Tags: debugging, gdb, embedded, insight, ddd-debugger

I have the script that pre-configures host, runs sh4-linux-gdb, connects to target and pre-configures it. After script execution I get regular (gdb) prompt.

Is there any way to "bind" this output to insigt or ddd, and control this instance via gui ?

I have tried different solution, but I can not success. I wouldn`t like to analyse the script. It is complex, nested, for different platforms and different projects.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

For Insight the answer is definitely no.  Insight is linked into gdb, it does not run a separate gdb.  So once you have started gdb, it is too late.

For DDD the answer is, "maybe, but only with extreme difficulty".  I don't believe there is any pre-canned way to do it.  You could maybe accomplish it if you were desperate by playing games with changing the current gdb's controlling terminal to something set up by DDD.

I would say that maybe you're better off either just changing this script to invoke DDD (or a newer GUI -- DDD is quite old and uses the wrong approach to gdb interaction) directly.  You probably don't need to understand the whole script to accomplish this.